# Javascript scope of array and converting js array to a php array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

**Edit/Clarification:**  I have a php page, call it displayPhotos.php, in which I set up an Ajax call to a different php page, call it getPhotos.php, which queries a database and returns photo information (caption, file name etc) to displayPhotos.php where they are displayed. I use php in displayPhotos to manipulate the data returned from getPhotos. The returned data from the Ajax call is a javascript 2-dimensional array. I need to turn the javascript array into a php array so I can do they display and other stuff.  How do I do that?
Hope this helps.

---

My eyes hurt from reading all of the docs.

I want to use ajax to query a database, return the data then use php to continue with the web page.

All of the examples I've looked at start with creating the json in php. I need to start with the json object in javascript.

```
   <script>
   var photoarray = [];
   var ajaxRequest = $.ajax
        ({
          url : "fhs_get_photos.php",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(photo_array)
           {
              photoarray = photo_array;
            //line below works. the file name is correct but disappears 
            //outside of this function
           console.log("photoarray[0][file_name] is: " + photoarray[0]['file_name']); 
           },

          error: function(request, status, error) 
           {  
              alert('An error occurred: ' );
           }
        });
```

In this instance I'm not passing anything to the php file that query's the db. The console log shows that the file name in photoarray is correct but once outside of this function it disappears even though it's declared as global, I think it is anyway. Why and what do I need to do to fix this.

The php file just does a SELECT * FROM..... and returns everything.

```
    // in fhs_get_photos.php
    // SELECT * FROM table......
   echo $json = json_encode($result);
   return $json;
```

So I now have the array back but it's in javascript. Once I figure out the scope problem, how can I convert this javascript array to a php array?

```
    <h3>Welcome to the Historical Society's historical photo archive
    </h3>
    </header>
    <figure id="photo_figure">
        <script>
        //line below gets me: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'thumb' of
        //undefined or null reference
        console.log("photoarray thumb: ") + photoarray[0]['thumb'];
        </script>
```

Am I explaining this properly?

Comment: If you are choosing ajax, there is no passing to php again, php render has already happened and unless you refresh, won´t happen again. You need to manually edit/create the dom you need in your success function with the new data

Comment: I don't understand, why do you need to convert js array to php array and where it should happen? Your response comes as JSON, you have to parse it "photoarray = JSON.parse(photo_array)". After that it's yours to use, If it's saved to global scope - then it should be visible to other scripts (IF they are executed after the response is recieved)

Comment: @juvian See my clarification.  How can I create the dom using php with the data contained in the javascript array?

Answer (score 1):

First of all AJAX is async. This means it sends the request when you ask it to, but receives the response sometime later in the future. And it works after php has rendered and sent the page. So. When you get an update via AJAX, you have to use javascript to make that update matter. The most simple solution is to process the response right there in the success callback. That way you don't need to mess with the global scope (which is a bad practice).

Supposedly, your HTML is like this:

```
   <header>
     <h3>Welcome to the Historical Society's historical photo archive
     </h3>
   </header>
   <div id="figures"></div>
```

You can do it by declaring a function that handles the processing:

```
function updateDom(photoArr) {
  var $figures = $('#figures');

  $.each(photoArr, function() {
    console.log(this);
    $figures.append('<img src="' + this.thumb +'">');
  });
}
```

**Code below is placed in the success callback**

And execute that function in the success callback and pass it the array from json, that was parsed and became a valid js object.

```
var photoArray = JSON.parse(photo_array);
updateDom(photoArray);
```

here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stwjLnnq/3/), but it's for the DOM part only

Comment: thanks for the reply. If I understand you correctly all of the php code is executed before any javascript code is executed. The javascript creates the Ajax request, sends it, and receives the data back. All of the php code has already been executed so there is no way I can do any further php processing. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes. PHP first, then all synchronous js, then asynchronous js (events, AJAX, etc). There's no way to know when exactly async parts will be executed, hence all the code they need to execute should be somehow chained to them. Callback functions is the default pattern for doing that chaining. Also there are promises, but it's better to understand callbacks first.
But Ajax is making a request. That request is processed by PHP, so there is PHP that is run during async js part. You can render html with that php and send it to js. Then you'll have to use js to append that html where it belongs.